# Ember.js computed: Shortest way to return single object from array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, computed-observable

Given an array of objects with ids:

```
array: [
    {id: 3, value: 'foo'},
    {id: 6, value: 'bar'},
    {id: 9, value: 'baz'},
    // ...
],
```

What is the shortest way to return a single object from the array that matches an `id`?
Keep in mind that the array can be `undefined` while the model is loading. In that case, the computed property should also return `undefined`.

This works:

```
_test       : computed.filterBy('array', 'id', 6),
test        : computed.alias('_test.firstObject')
```

But it is not pretty, using a temporary variable.

This is better:

```
test        : computed('array.[]', function() {
    let array = this.get('array')
    if (array) return array.find(el => el.id == 6)
})
```

But it is not pretty, because it uses 4 lines.

Ember contains a lot of syntactic sugar, but I haven't figured out how to shrink this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `filter` and `filterBy` will reduce an array to just the list of items you're filtering to.

If you want a single item from the list, use `find` or `findBy`.

In your case, you'll use the following.

```
test: computed('array.[]', function() {
    return this.getWithDefault('array',[])
        .findBy('id',6)
})
```

When you're done, `this.get('test')` will return `{id: 6, value: 'bar'}`

More information can be found in the documentation for [MutableArray](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/MutableArray/methods/findBy?anchor=findBy)

Comment: I didn't know about `getWithDefault` to prevent errors. Thank you.